# Issue with pandas df.get_dummies() for Hot Encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
 df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df[1005], prefix=1005, prefix_sep=0)
```

I'm experiencing an issue with this method of pandas dataframe, basically the first column name it return contains a special character '-' that nobody specified...
I need these name to be converted to int numbers in the future, so this is a problem for me. I don't want to remove it manually since I want a flexible solution for future change. I already searched on google but no one seems to have faced this problem before.

```
Index(['10050-0.0', '100501.0', '100502.0', '100503.0', '100504.0', '100505.0',
       '100506.0', '100507.0'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Instructions unclear. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was asking what determine the names of new columns and why the first name contain that character.

Comment: Did you even read the link? You didn't provide any data. How do you expect help?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem is. 
The name of the new colums are the set of values within the column given to get_dummies()

Within my df[1005] were stored negative zero (float -0.0)